# Odd javascript notation - what does it mean?

Tags: javascript

Just looking over a [cool tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-coronavirus-covid-19-dashboard-map-app-in-react-with-gatsby-and-leaflet/#what-are-we-going-to-build) and there was a notation that I didn't completely understand and having a hell of a time trying to google it.

```
async function mapEffect({ leafletElement: map } = {}) {
    let response;

    try {
      response = await axios.get(‘https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries’);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(`Failed to fetch countries: ${e.message}`, e);
      return;
    }

    // this next line here is the one confusing me:
    const { data = [] } = response;
}
```

Reading on, it appears that data is just an array - any reason it is written like this?  Can anyone explain in layman's terms why you would write something this way?  I never stop learning...  Thank you!

Comment: Which line do you mean? If you mean `{ data = [] }` this is _destructuring_ with a default value.

Comment: `const { data = [] } = response; 

const data = response.data || [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that piece of code is doing is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) an object.

Destructuring  lets you bind variables to different properties of an object. When you specify the property being bound, it will then be followed by the variable you are binding its value to.

Here is a basic example:

```js
const { foo, bar } = { foo: "hello", bar: "world" };
console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
//1st letter
console.log(foo[0]);
console.log(bar[0]);
```

In your case it has a default value as fallback ( `[]` an array in case your response comes empty)

You can read more about it [here](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-default-values/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
const { data = [] } = response;
```

is equal to

```js
// [] is default value if response.data is empty
const data = response.data || [];
```

Comment: Rather `response.data ?? []` :)

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah sure, but isn't it still experimental ?

Comment: Kind of, yes. Think it's already in the standard, and all major browsers support it. But probably not stable enough for prod yet, and probably not much of use for an explanation (exchanging one unknown syntax with another). Just wanted to point out that you might want to clarify the exact behaviour of object destructuring with defaults, maybe also link some docs?

Comment: @JonasWilms btw "dippas" made decent job to provide useful docs and a good demonstration of destructing declartion. I just wanted to explain the code  a little simpler